# Как организовать простой консольный чат?

Tags: java, многопоточность, сокет, chat

Всем привет.

Изучаю Java, дошёл до потоков. Пытаюсь реализовать простой чат, суть в следующем:

- клиент подключается к серверу (сокету)

..отдельно клиент писать не стал, использую "telnet localhost port". Из-за этого есть ряд проблем, например, когда человек вводит что-то и нажимает "Ввод", он видит не только своё сообщение в виде "его_ник: всем привет" но и просто "всем привет" ввиду "принципа работы" консоли. Но я не знаю как это исправить, если честно. Не думал пока.

- сервер спрашивает желаемый никнейм
- спрашивает хочет ли клиент видеть только последние сообщения или всю дискуссию
- выводит соответствующее количество сообщений
- пользователь вводит сообщение, нажимает Enter
- все клиенты видят это новое сообщение (сразу, то есть некоторые могут и не писать ничего, а просто сидеть и читать что другие пишут)

Код:

```java
package ru.just.a.guy;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Server {
    //the variable for monitor
    public static final Object flag = new Object();
    //create variable for the server port
    public static final int SERVER_PORT = 9090;
    // the list of messages
    public static final List<String> messagesList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //create server socket to be able to create an instance of a client socket
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);
        //create a new thread pool
        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        //create an endless loop so that the server runs without stopping
        while (true){
            //waiting for a client connection
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            //send new job for a thread
                exec.submit(() -> {
                    try {
                        processConnection(clientSocket);
                    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ignore) {
                    }
                });
        }
    }
    //method for processing new connections
    private static void processConnection(Socket clientSocket) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        //flag for more recent or all
        boolean seeAll = true;
        //nickname variable
        String nickname = null;
        //create in and out streams
        Writer output = new OutputStreamWriter(
                new BufferedOutputStream(
                        clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        //welcome a new user and ask for a nickname
        output.write("Welcome to the chat!\n"+"\r");
        output.write("Please, enter your nickname:\n"+"\r");
        output.flush();
        nickname = input.readLine();
        //ask if he wants to see everything or just the most recent posts
        output.write("What would you like to see?\n"+"\r");
        output.write("1. All messages\n"+"\r");
        output.write("2. Some recent ones\n"+"\r");
        output.flush();
        //read the option number
        int optionN = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        //if the user wants to see the recent posts, we change the flag
        if (optionN==2){seeAll=false;}
        output.write("-----------The chat-----------\n"+"\r");
        output.flush();
        //show the previous messages
        for (String line:displayPrevious(seeAll)) {output.write(line+"\n"+"\r");}
        output.flush();
            while (true) {
                synchronized (messagesList) {
                    String message = input.readLine();
                    messagesList.add(nickname + ": " + message + "\n" + "\r");
                    output.write(nickname + ": " + message + "\n" + "\r");
                    output.flush();
                    messagesList.notifyAll();
                    messagesList.wait();
                    output.write(messagesList.get(messagesList.size()-1));
                }
            }
        }

    //method for getting messages (all or the 15 last entries in the list)
    private static ArrayList<String> displayPrevious(boolean allOrRecent) {
            //put all messages in a temporary collection
            ArrayList<String> forDisplay = new ArrayList<>(messagesList);
            //if the flag for all messages is true, return the full collection
            //if not, return the last 15 entries
            if (allOrRecent) {
                return forDisplay;
            } else {
                ArrayList<String> recentMessages = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 15; i >= 1; i--) {
                    recentMessages.add(forDisplay.get(forDisplay.size() - i));
                }
                return recentMessages;
            }
    }
}
```

Сейчас проблема в том, что при появлении нового сообщения, оно не выскакивает у всех, вместо этого оно появляется по-разному от случая к случаю, например, когда кто-то отправил своё сообщение. Вместе с сообщением появится и другое, отправленное предыдущим пользователем.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я сделал не так? Хотелось бы чтобы оно работало как типичный общий чат.

Спасибо.

P.S

Да, я знаю, что это всё не очень сложно, но, как и сказал, я не скрываю, что я начинающий (:

P.S[2]

Да, исключения пока не обрабатывал, хочу, чтобы оно хоть как-то заработало сначала)

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-websockets

Answer (score 0):

Рассмотри внимательно

```
            while (true) {
            synchronized (messagesList) {
                String message = input.readLine();
                messagesList.add(nickname + ": " + message + "\n" + "\r");
                output.write(nickname + ": " + message + "\n" + "\r");
                output.flush();
                messagesList.notifyAll();
                messagesList.wait();
                output.write(messagesList.get(messagesList.size()-1));
            }
        }
```

Так же почитай про режим гонки в многопоточных системах. Думаю ты разберешься :)